# sfWidgetFormInputText with dropdown menu

Tags: php, symfony1, symfony-1.4, symfony-forms

I have an input field like this in `lib/form`:

```
'zipcode' => new sfWidgetFormInputText(array(), array('size' => '40', 'maxlength' => '100', 'value' => $t,
         //   'onblur' => "if(this.value == &#039;&#039;) { this.value=&#039;$t&#039;}",
            'onfocus' => "if (this.value == &#039;$t&#039;) {this.value=&#039;&#039;}",
            'choices' =>  array('c' => '', 'm' => '12345', 'f' => '98765')
        )),
```

`choices` option doesn't work. Is there any option when I click into the zipcode that a dropdown list with some zipcodes appear?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no standard HTML field to do what you want. You can either:

- use a simple text input
- use a dropdown list (`select`)
- use some javascript to somehow combine the two (also known as autocomplete)